# index.html not getting generated using HtmlWebpackPlugin in webpack config

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code

I am trying to generate html using HtmlWebpackPlugin, 
my config file is as below

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
 module.exports = {
        entry: './src/app.js',
        output: {
                path:'dist',
                filename: 'app.bundle.js'
           },
        plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
        }
```

when i keep

```
output: {
        filename: 'dist/app.bundle.js'
   },
```

then index.html gets generated in dist folder

but when i keep

```
output: {
        path:'dist',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
   },
```

after separating filename and path then it doesn't get generated.
I tried making path to ./dist and also tried writing like below

```
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
```

but still no luck.
I know the issue is related to path only but how exactly i need to mention in case of writing path and filename separately.

Can someone make out what is missing?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: path: './dist/'

Comment: tried this as well, dint work:(

Comment: Are you using verison 4 of webpack? Just simply emit the path property, it goes by default to /dist

Comment: Gr8!!!...It worked after removing path property